# Extension to BindingList<T> that allows for cancelable notifications of changing and deleting

Tags: c#, collections, databinding

This is an extension of the `System.ComponentModel.BindingList<T>` class that allows for notifications of item changing and deleting. These notifications provided the outgoing item and the incoming item, as well as a `Cancel` property to cancel the change or deletion.

In additon, it also allows for a bulk addition of items, which is just a loop of `AddItem` (which will trigger a change notification for each item added).

On top of bulk addition, there is a `SetItems` which will clear the collection and add all the items provided, but will only fire one `Reset` notification.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BindingListExtension
{
    public class BindingListEx<T> : BindingList<T>
    {
        public event EventHandler<ListItemRemovingEventArgs<T>> ListItemRemoving;
        public event EventHandler<ListItemChangingEventArgs<T>> ListItemChanging;

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            var args = new ListItemRemovingEventArgs<T>(this[index], index);
            ListItemRemoving?.Invoke(this, args);
            if (args.Cancel) return;
            base.RemoveItem(index);
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
        {
            var args = new ListItemChangingEventArgs<T>(this[index], item, index);
            ListItemChanging?.Invoke(this, args);
            if (args.Cancel) return;
            base.SetItem(index, item);
        }

        public void SetItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
            Clear();
            AddItems(items);
            RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
            OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
        }

        public void AddItems(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            if (items != null)
            {
                foreach (T item in items)
                {
                    Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class ListItemRemovingEventArgs<T> : CancelEventArgs
    {
        public ListItemRemovingEventArgs(T oldItem, int index)
        {
            OldItem = oldItem;
        }

        public T OldItem { get; }

        public int Index { get; }
    }

    public class ListItemChangingEventArgs<T> : ListItemRemovingEventArgs<T>
    {
        public ListItemChangingEventArgs(T oldItem, T newItem, int index) : base(oldItem, index)
        {
            NewItem = newItem;
        }

        public T NewItem { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not need for a new type. Since `RaiseListChangedEvents` is a public property both methods (`SetItems` & `AddItems`) could be extension methods. I find the behaviour of `SetItems` is pretty unexpected because it clears the collection and not like the original `SetItem` updates items at specific indexes which it should be doing. What you have written is more like `ResetItems` and you seem to have forgotten to disable rasing events in `AddItems`.

Comment: @t3chb0t I believe _Add_ calls _SetItem_ internally (not sure), so an event is raised.

Answer (score 1):

#### ListChangedType.Reset

`AddItems` is nothing more than a glorified wrapper method for calling `Add` multiple times. However, guidelines suggest that [ListChangedType.Reset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.listchangedtype?view=netframework-4.8) could and probably should also be called here. Since `Reset` should be called when..

> Much of the list has changed. Any listening controls should refresh
>   all their data from the list.

To give this method some purpose other than looping elements and call `Add`, consider using the same deferral strategy as you did with `SetItems`.